# Why does this code won't work? It displays 0

Tags: c

Whenever I compile it displays 0 instead of 11. what is wrong this code?  I used a function add. I notice that this works when I'm using an array string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

void add(int result, int a, int b);

int main(void) {
    int num1 = 5;
    int num2 = 6;
    int result1 = 0;
    add(result1, num1, num2);

 printf("%d", result1);

 return 0;
}

 void add(int result, int a, int b) {
  result = a + b;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Arguments of C functions are *copies* of what are passed, so modifying them in callee will not affect what is passed in caller.

To have functions modify passed things, you should pass *pointers* to what should be modified.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(int *result, int a, int b); /* add * to make result a pointer */

int main(void) {
  int num1 = 5;
  int num2 = 6;
  int result1 = 0;
  add(&result1, num1, num2); /* add & to pass a pointer */

  printf("%d", result1);

  return 0;
}

void add(int *result, int a, int b) { /* add * to make result a pointer */
  *result = a + b; /* add * to dereference the pointer */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the changes done by the operation performed inside the method `add` in not visible outside. Those arguments that you have passed are being [pass by value](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Egermain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/c_functions.html)

> **Pass by Value**
>
> Pass by Value, means that a copy of the data is made and stored by way
> of the name of the parameter. **Any changes to the parameter have NO
> affect on data in the calling function.**

To made those changes visible to the outside you can pass the memory reference of the `result` variable (*i.e.,* [pass-by-reference](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Egermain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/c_functions.html))

> **Pass by Reference**
>
> A reference parameter "refers" to the original data in the calling
> function. **Thus any changes made to the parameter are ALSO MADE TO THE
> ORIGINAL variable.**

For example:

```
void add(int *result, int a, int b) {
  *result = a + b;
}
```

and call the in the `main` as follows:

```
add(&result1, num1, num2);
```

or return the result of the operation as follows :

```
int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

and call it in the main as follows:

```
result1 = add(num1, num2);
```